# Avro data file gui viewer/editor

Tags: data-visualization, gui, file-format

while working with binary data format files - Apache Avro it would be handy to have some viewer/editor at least for QA.
I tried protobuf editor which works great for protocol buffers and have some plugin for avro called avro editor. It works fine for simple avro schemas which doesn't contain unions. What is very limiting and for practical use cases not usable.

Requirements:

- should support all Avro data types (primitive and complex) - serve as
  data file viewer
- we are not interested in any avro RPC related features
- run on Windows or Linux OS
- GUI applicaiton (something similar to protobuf editor if posible)

One alternative is to use a avro tools and convert it to json and view json. We would like to remove the intermediate step if possible.

Does anybody knows some alternative?

Comment: The Avro Editor https://sourceforge.net/projects/avroeditor/ does support Unions now. Its a bit clunky though (all options are listed on a screen). The Supplied Avro libraries are old and may need updating

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Avro tools can fit your need. It doesn't have a GUI, but it's provided directly by Apache ([direct JAR download](http://apache.websitebeheerjd.nl/avro/avro-1.7.7/java/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar)).

More about this tools on the Michael Nool's [blog post](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [bigdata-file-viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer/), it's a cross-platform (Windows, MAC, Linux) desktop application to view common bigdata binary format like Parquet, ORC, Avro, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple tool that allows you to view avro files and convert them to json and csv formats, I hope it will be useful for you. https://dataformat.net/avro/viewer-and-converter